# Passing props into component which has v-if set

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a page with a stepper. I conditionally display a step, based on what step user is on. When flicks between steps (user can go back and forth) I noticed that my props are no longer passed over. What can be done about it?

View page:

```
<v-container v-if="stepNumber === 1">
  <sectionOne :restrictions="restrictions" />
</v-container>

<v-container v-if="stepNumber === 2">
  <sectionTwo :restrictions="restrictions" />
</v-container>
```

Within a section component:

```
@Prop() readonly restrictions: RestrictionsDomain = new RestrictionsDomain([]);
```

I understand that I can avoid a need for passing a prop with help of vuex, but I am wondering if anything can be done to get my props to work as is? Also, I can't use `v-show` for this either.

Comment: There's not enough context to determine the problem. Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 1):

Since `v-if` destroys the element, thus removing the props' reactivity, and if you can't use `v-show`, I'd consider using a watcher on the prop and setting another reactive variable that'd trigger the visibility of that element.

So you'd get something like this:

```html
<v-container v-if="step === 1">
  <sectionOne :restrictions="restrictions" />
</v-container>

<v-container v-if="step === 2">
  <sectionTwo :restrictions="restrictions" />
</v-container>
```

```js
props: ['stepNumber'],
data() {
  return {
    step: 1,
  }
},
watch: {
  stepNumber(newVal) {
    this.step = newVal
  }
}
```